# Manually drawing at coordinates inside a wrap panel

Tags: c#, wpf, image, wrappanel

In my application I have several(!) (wrap) panels which contains small thumbnails (`Image`) (Thumbnails are generated on the fly, so no xaml). I wish to show which thumbnail I "select" by drawing a "glowing" border over it.

To do this I went and wrote a "`selectElement`" function:

```
private void SelectElement(FrameworkElement elem)
{
    if (elem == _selectedElement) return;
    _selectedElement = elem;
    var parentPanel = _selectionBorder?.Parent as Panel;
    if (parentPanel != null)
    {
        parentPanel.Children.Remove(_selectionBorder);
    }
    _selectionBorder = null;
    if (_selectedElement == null) return;
    _selectionBorder = new Border
    {
        BorderThickness = new Thickness(10),
        BorderBrush = Brushes.Black
    };

    var p = _selectedElement.Parent as Panel;
    if (p == null) return;
    p.Children.Add(_selectionBorder);
    var m = _selectedElement.Margin;
    _selectionBorder.Margin = m;
}
```

Which will be called from a `MouseDown` event for the `Image`;
Now the problem is: Even though I set the margin for the border to the same as the element, the border is added after all elements. Is it possible to "bypass" the default wrappanel behaviour for this border? - Or is it possible to actually draw a "border around my thumbnail `Image`"? - Without actually increasing the image's size (The "semitransparent border" should blend with the image to the sides).

PS: Yes I realize that this would mean the border is "cut" when the thumbnail is close to the wrappanel's border itself but I'm ok with that.

Comment: Sounds like you want an [`Adorner`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743737(v=vs.110).aspx). WPF provides a layer where adorners can be shown, without being part of the visual tree of the elements being adorned. There are [lots of questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bwpf%5D+adorner) about adorners already on Stack Overflow. Your question is far too broad as it is. Take a look a the information available, and if you have a _specific_ problem, post a new question which includes a good [mcve] and details about what you tried and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well simply "you need an Adorner" is enough of an answer for me to let me figure out the rest. - It's just that googling, "borders around elements" etc doesn't go anywhere near the term "adorner". Thanks.